# AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData deprecated

Tags: core-audio

I'm testing the sound recording on Mac, by using the following code

```
OSStatus error;
AudioDeviceID deviceID = 0;

AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress;
UInt32 propertySize;
propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice;
propertyAddress.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
propertyAddress.mElement = 0;
propertySize = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);
error = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject,
                                            &propertyAddress,
                                            0,
                                            NULL,
                                            &propertySize,
                                            &deviceID);
if(error)
    return error;

propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate;
propertyAddress.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
propertyAddress.mElement = 0;
propertySize = sizeof(Float64);
error = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(deviceID,
                                            &propertyAddress,
                                            0,
                                            NULL,
                                            &propertySize,
                                            outSampleRate);
```

But Xcode gave me that the AudioHardwareService*** are deprecated from OS X 10.11.

I checked the Apple's API guide, but I can't find any replacement for these APIs.

I know it works, but all these warnings are so annoying. 
What should I do?

Comment: As for silencing the compiler, I don't know - deprecated is not retired. Else, can you try using `AudioHardwareGetProperty()`? It is well documented. You can even get a range of available nominal sample rates.

Answer (score 7):

In your case, simply substituting `AudioObjectGetPropertyData` for `AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData` should suffice; see [TN2223](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2223/_index.html).